# Distributing a PHP cron job script across many different AWS servers

Tags: php, database, indexing, cron, distribution

I have a cron job script that runs every 60 seconds to process and store results in a database. That’s a maximum of 1,440 new database entries per day.

I need to have many many millions of database entries, so doing this with just one instance of this script is really impractical. I’m looking for a minimum of a 50x speed up, and ideally 300x to 500x if the cost is reasonable.

It seems like I need a server farm, but I have to use Amazon Web Services to process this data. How can I set this script up to run many simultaneous instances, while storing the data in a single, unified database?

Do I need to create completely separate server instances for every time I want to run this script, multiplying the cost?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why use cron instead of a task/job queue? Gearman, RabbitMQ etc

Comment: Why does your cron script add only one entry? Can't it add multiple entries?

Answer (score 0):

A serverless approach using a remote lambda function to execute your job triggered by a queue system solve your problem both technically and at pricing level.

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

For example you can trigger a lambda function execution from a local centralized script (eg. by a single cron) which enqueue some messages to a queue system for as many entries you need to compute in an asyncronous/concurrent way.

The serverless framework can help you to avoid AWS lock-in:
https://serverless.com/